# Unreachable code in JSP file

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, syntax-error

This below code is my one of tsp code.

At the bottom ' %> ' it shows unreachable code.
Everything should work correctly I think.

Also from the other code, I got this happen, but I cut and paste it again it worked, but this above code.

Every bracket also looks great.

I don't know why.
Please help me.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import ="board.BoardDTO" %>
<%@ page import ="board.BoardDAO" %>
<%@ page import ="util.SHA256" %>
<%@ page import ="java.io.PrintWriter" %>
<%
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
String userID=null;
String boardTitle=null;
String boardDesc=null;



if(session.getAttribute("userID") != null){
    userID = (String) session.getAttribute("userID");
}
if(session.getAttribute("boardTitle") != null){
    boardTitle = (String) session.getAttribute("boardTitle");
}
if(session.getAttribute("boardDesc") != null){
    boardDesc = (String) session.getAttribute("boardDesc");
}

if(userID == null){
    PrintWriter script =response.getWriter();
    script.println("<script>");
    script.println("alert(userID);");
    script.println("history.back();");
    script.println("</script>");
    script.close();
    return;

} else{
    if(boardTitle == null || boardDesc ==null){
        PrintWriter script =response.getWriter();
        script.println("<script>");
        script.println("alert('You did not title or content');");
        script.println("history.back();");
        script.println("</script>");
        script.close();
        return;


    }
    else{
        BoardDAO boardDao = new BoardDAO();

        int result = boardDao.write(boardTitle, userID, boardDesc);
        if(result == -1 ){
            PrintWriter script =response.getWriter();
            script.println("<script>");
            script.println("alert('Failed.');");
            script.println("history.back();");
            script.println("</script>");
            script.close();
            return;


        }else{
            PrintWriter script =response.getWriter();
            script.println("<script>");
            script.println("location.href = 'board.jsp'");
            script.println("</script>");
            script.close();
            return;

        }
    }
}
%>
```

Comment: There are a few (empty) lines which cannot be reached with this logic tree. Try using a single `return` at the very end of the function, preceeded by a single `script.close();`.

Comment: so use 'return' on last statement else{
            PrintWriter script =response.getWriter();
            script.println("<script>");
            script.println("location.href = 'board.jsp'");
            script.println("</script>");
            script.close();
            return;

        }

Comment: "at the very end of the function" just before the **last** `}`. Or otherwise just move a single copy of those two lines at different places by trial and error. Soon you will find what I mean - or so I hope.